# spilt string with dot but dot not lies in single quote using jquery or regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to split a string like this, on dot. But I don't want to split on dot that are inside of a string (' or "). I'm not parsing a file; just a simple string with no line breaks.

```
part 1;"12:'xyz@gmail.com'.8:'23'.25:'hello'.6:6"
```

Result should be:

```
part 1 "12:'xyz@gmail.com'"
part 2 "8:'23'"
part 3 "25:'hello'"
part 4 "6:6"
```

I suppose this can be done with a regex but if not; I'm open to another approach.

*EDIT*

I have

```
str = "12:'xyz@gmail.com'.8:'23'.25:'hello'.6:6"
```

and I expect to get

```
str[0]=12:xyz@gmail.com str[1]=8:'23' 
str[2]=25:'hello' 
str[3]=6:6
```

but whenever i split it, it shows like that:

```
str[0]=12:xyz@gmail
str[1]=com
str[2]=8:'23'
str[3]=25:'hello'
str[4]=6:6
```

Comment: I want to split a string by dot like :-
str = "12:'xyz@gmail.com'.8:'23'.25:'hello'.6:6"
str[0]=12:xyz@gmail.com
str[1]=8:'23'
str[2]=25:'hello'
str[3]=6:6

but whenever i spilt it, it shows like that:-
str[0]=12:xyz@gmail
str[1]=com
str[2]=8:'23'
str[3]=25:'hello'
str[4]=6:6

please help me to sort out this

Comment: i don't want to split 'xyz@gmail.com' by dot, i.e. if dot lies between single quotes than it doesn't split.

Comment: Please add the code with the description of the issue to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *match* with the following regex:

```
/[^.']+(?:'[^']*')?/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oO0cK0/1)

*Details:*

- `[^.']+` - 1 or more characters other than `'` and `.`
- `(?:'[^']*')?` - an optional `'...'` string (`'` followed with 0+ characters other than `'` followed with a `'`.

Depending on what the content can be, you can use an enhanced version:

```
/[^.']*(?:'[^']*'[^.']*)*/g
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/oO0cK0/3)

Demo 1 (simplified):

```js
var re = /[^.']+(?:'[^']*')?/g; 
var str = '12:\'xyz@gmail.com\'.8:\'23\'.25:\'hello\'.6:6';
var m = str.match(re);
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(m, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Demo 2 (if the contents are more complex):

```js
var re = /[^.']*(?:'[^']*'[^.']*)*/g; 
var str = '\'1.2\' 12:\'xyz@gmail.com\'.8:\'23\'.25:\'hello\'.6:6';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    if (m[0]) { res.push(m[0]);}
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Comment: @rock321987: I added another solution for more complex input.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about split, but you can use `replace` like this (prone to catastrophic backtracking)

```
((?:(?:'[^']+')*[^.']*)*)(?:\.|$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qI9mD0/)**

*JS Code*

```js
var re = /((?:(?:'[^']+')*[^.']*)*)(?:\.|$)/g; 
var str = '\'1.2\':\'xyz@mail.com\'.8:\'2.3\'.25:\'he.llo\'.6:6\'1.2\''
document.writeln("<pre>" + str.replace(re, "$1\n") + "</pre>");
```

Comment: Your solution is somewhat unnecessarily complicated. You have optional subpatterns inside a `*` quantified group - that looks a bit dangerous. Look at [this demo of your regex](https://regex101.com/r/qE5hT7/1) and the same demo for [mine](https://regex101.com/r/qE5hT7/2). Surely, the input is not real-life, but you get the gist.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for suggestion..i was in a bit of hurry..so i wrote whatever I could think at that time

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp:

`new RegExp('(\.[^\:]+\:\'?[^\.]+\'?)','g');`